# How to download file from Cloud Storage inside Cloud Run container?

Tags: linux, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I want to download a file from cloud storage whenever my cloud run container starts. I have modified the dockerfile to add the following command:

```
CMD curl -L -o - application.yml "gs://mybucket/application.yml" ;
```

Unfortunately, it looks like gs: protocol is not supported by curl so that is the error I am getting.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application.yml
curl: (1) Protocol "gs" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

How do I achieve this?
According to [Cloud Run Docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services), I don't need to worry about authentication as long as cloud run and cloud storage stay in the same google cloud project. What am I missing here? This feels like a very basic requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download using just curl, there are examples here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#download-object-xml
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#download-object-json

Since you happen to "know" that you are in a Cloud Run instance, you should be able to use just `curl` to get an access token through the metadata service
at the `http://metadata.google.internal` endpoint. More details here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default

Most likely the key you want is `service-accounts/default/token`, but maybe you need to replace `default` with the email for whatever service account you are using.

PS: The Cloud Run documentation you referenced says:

> You do not need to provide credentials manually inside Cloud Run (fully managed) container instances **when using the Google Cloud client libraries**. (emphasis mine)